# jQuery adding html to the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete, format

my input array has:

```
results[num_row] = {
    'title': title,
    'url': url,
    'support_url': support_url,
    'description': description,
    'contacts': contacts
};
```

I get the results back:

```
function formatItem(item){
   var highlight = $.Autocompleter.defaults.highlight;
   var temp = '<span class="title">' + highlight(item.title, term)  + '</span>';
   temp += '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.description;
   return temp;
} 

function prep(){
$("#searchbox").autocomplete(results,{
    width:500,
    scroll:false,
    formatItem: formatItem,
    highlight: false

}).result(function(event, item) {
    location.href = item.url;
});
}
```

I'd like to be able to add tags to what is being returned so that I can override the colors using css. For example I'd like to do something like:

```
formatItem: function(item) {
    var temp = '<span class="title">' + item.title + </span> + '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + <span class="description"> + item.description + </span>;
    return temp;
}
```

When I try adding the tags inline like that, it changes the input search critera to having that literal tag. So I have to actually type `<span class="title">Search String` in order to search instead of `Search String`.

Thank you.

Comment: I fixed the formatting, but there are syntax errors in the 2nd and 3rd code blocks. I am not sure if they are intentional. Do you see them? Please fix them to avoid red herrings.

Comment: Thank you for making it easier to read. I'll make sure to do that in the future. Please tell me what the syntax errors are. This is my first run in with jQuery and javascript for the most part, do you happen to know the answer to my question? Thank you again.

Comment: You have an extra `'` (making half the code red), and you have a wandering `}`.

Comment: Look closely how the code is been highlighted. There are some singlequotes `'` missing or too much in both blocks and there's also one `}` too much in 2nd block.

Comment: oh i see, thats because i didn't paste all of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is being run through `options.highlight` afterwards.  Try specifying a highlight function which returns the source string:

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete(results, {
    formatItem: function(item, foo, bar, term) {
        var highlight = $.Autocompleter.defaults.highlight;
        var temp = '<span class="title">' + highlight(item.title, term)  + '</span>';
        temp += '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + item.description;

        return temp;
    },

    highlight: false
}).result(function(event, item) {
    location.href = item.url;
});
```

Be sure you're escaping `item.title` to prevent XSS attacks!

Comment: I think you're right. I looked at this question and it seams to be pretty much the same problem. Trying to implement now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381859/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-custom-highlight-function

Comment: Could someone help me with the code I need for the highlight to work. I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381859/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-custom-highlight-function but wasn't able to hack it.

Comment: @specked, See my edit.  I don't know how the autocomplete plugin works, so it's mostly a guess.

Comment: thanks, I added it and cleaned up my code a little to make it more readable. I am getting a "term is not defined" error for  var `var temp = '<span class="title">' + highlight(item.title, term)  + '</span>';`

Comment: @specked, You're missing the added parameters to the `formatItem` function.  `term` is the fourth parameter (`arguments[3]`).